# How often do failed operations get included in the blockchain?

Tags: operation

My understanding is that failed transaction [like this](https://tzkt.io/onuEbjVrbaXtn4iK8KFzc4a8xTkfkyAfxiNE698SLm3MtnimdUs) should be checked by the node before injecting the operation, but either because of a bug in the node software, or because an operation that hadn't been observed managed to front run the operation when getting baked. Is that correct?

And also how often do failed/backtracked operations end up getting baked? Are there any stats on this?